# Why and how does Django send HTTP 200OK for example.com to AWS Scanner

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx

I'm running Django 3.0 on Ubuntu in AWS cloud and in my Nginx logs I see the following:

```
44.224.22.196 - - [02/Apr/2020:18:49:13 +0530] "GET http://example.com/ HTTP/1.1" **200** 396 "-" "AWS Security Scanner"
```

Question 1:
example.com is their in my Django sites but I haven't put it in allowed hosts (in settings.py). Neither example.com exists in my Nginx's server block, then why does Nginx send HTTP 200 to AWS Scanner?

Question 2:
How did the request for example.com reach my server. I haven't done IP binding for it neither in AWS nor in my server.

Comment: Your nginx.conf file by default includes a setting that accepts all hosts. Probably the "server block" you're talking about is inside a .conf file in `sites-available`. Check the default.conf.

Comment: @dirkgroten Yes, I do have two files- "default" and "myproject" inside /etc/nginx/sites-available, and "default" file does have "example.com" but that's been commented out.

Answer (score 0):

This scanner is run by AWS Security, in relation to [Instance Metadata and User data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html).

Source: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=935467#935467

Comment: Thanks, I have already visited that link. I need to understand why does Nginx send HTTP 200 OK for a website that doesn't exist!

Comment: The scanner accesses the link-local address `169.254.169.254`. So the request happens locally on your instance and it is only valid from that instance. Here is an example that you can run in your ssh session `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-hostname`

Comment: Thanks Chris. Link local address explains how does that request come to my system. But I still don't understand what's send HTTP OK back. curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-hostname does show an xml doc like this: {{{<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">}}}. But it's not a request to example.com and neither does I see any HTTP get for this in my Nginx access logs